# Showing Error when removed question mark in url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

This is my url

```html
http://localhost/test/date/time?id1=Mw&id2=kk
```

When I removed question mark from url manually its showing following error

```html
http://localhost/test/date/timeid1=Mw&id2=kk
```

An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: Do you have a question or is it just a statement?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you remove the question mark?

Here is how routing works with CodeIgniter:

With `http://localhost/test/date/time?id1=Mw&id2=kk`,

- `http://localhost/` is your `base_url`.
- `test` is the name of your controller.
- `date` is the action (function) in your controller.
- `time` is the attribute passed to the action.
- `id1` and `id2` are superglobals with values `Mw` and `kk`.

You could use this snippet to work with that:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function date($type) // $type == 'time'
    {
        $id1 = $this->input->get('id1'); // '$id1 == Mw'
        $id2 = $this->input->get('id2'); // '$id2 == kk'
    }
}
```

if you remove the `?` character, the `$type` parameter will equal `timeid1=Mw&id2=kk`, which is forbidden.

## Alternative

You could use the URI: `http://localhost/test/date/time/Mw/kk` along with the action:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function date($type, $id1, $id2) // $type == 'time', '$id1 == Mw', '$id2 == kk'
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```